# how to get products collection in block magento 2?

Tags: magento2, blocks, products

> Actually I am trying to get products collection in block using
>   resource model class here I want to get the price of the first product if
>   product is configurable Magento 2.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Catproduct extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_storeManager;    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    protected $registry;  
    protected $_urlInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;  
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->registry = $registry;
         $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCategoryProducts($catalog_ids) 
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(9); // fetching only 3 products
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $catalog_ids));
        $collection->load();
        return $collection;
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: Is it working or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this below code in your function :

```
public function getCategoryProducts($catalog_ids) 
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(9); // fetching only 3 products
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $catalog_ids));
        $collection->load();
        foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
            if($value->getTypeId() == "configurable"){
                echo $value->getId()."--".$value->getFinalPrice()."<br/>";
            }
        }
        return $collection;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get configurable product price using below code

```
public function getCategoryProducts($catalog_ids) 
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPageSize(9); // fetching only 3 products
    $collection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $catalog_ids));
    $collection->load();
    foreach($collection as $key => $product)
    {
      if($key == 0 && $product->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {
        $finalPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price');
        echo $finalPrice->getValue();
      }
    }

}
```

Let me know if you need further assistance.